# Is NoSQL ideal for my use case

Tags: sql, nosql

One of our customer is in manufacturing domain. He has multiple factories across the country. For the quality control, he is using window application deployed independently in all factories (approx 100 in count). Our customer is interested in replacing all the window applications with a single web application. Now the problem is volume of the data will be 100 times bigger and same as the velocity (in case we keep a single database for all the factories). There are lots of reporting use cases in this domain. Looking at the numbers, it looks like SQL will be not be able to handle this much load.

Is it a valid use case to move to NoSQL database?

Can Volume/Velocity alone be a deciding factor to move to NoSQL?

Would we be able to get all those reporting from NoSQL database efficiently?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Without much more specifics this is completely unanswerable.

Comment: here main concern is how many applications uses your database?

Comment: Currently, there will be only one application that will use this database. In every second, 1-5 new readings need to be entered for a factory. One reading result into generally 10-15 new rows across 2-3 tables. If we count it for all the factories, number of rows  that will be inserted are 100-150 per second.

Comment: Yes , It’s a valid case , NoSQL databases are increasingly used in big data applications. Your applications seem to be producing 388m rows over month (In different tables n AS you said among 3 tables so 130m in each table).(It’s also depends on the size of a row , if it consist more numeric data it's more efficient to handle it) So here if you want to keep data prior to a month then it’s better to move towards NOSQL databases and NOSQL would definitely give you better results here.

Comment: @NagendraNigade - it wouldn't, and you are completely wrong. Under no circumstance can a nosql be faster than relational database when writing. All the benchmarks one can see are stupid, fake and made for ignorant idiots who can't understand where the "speed" comes from. The performance comes from the device that performs the write. A relational database **forces** the device to store the record, while a NoSQL will happily let OS queue the write task - and it sometimes fails. Use a relational database if you need **relations**. Use NoSQL if you don't care about relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a usefull discussion.

In my opinion a well designed MS-SQL server 2012 (or Oracle server, but no experience for me) must be capable of handling 1000 complex transactions per second.

MS-SQL server 2014 with in-memory processing raises even higher expecations.

Consider multi processor, large memories, table partitioning, file mapping, multiple access paths to the SAN or to separate server discs. Use well designed transactions (consider to remove most indexes on transaction tables).

As an extra benefit you keep all functionality of the SQL server. In my opinion most NOSQL solutions are NOSQL because they are deprived of essential SQL functionality.

Switch to NOSQL databases is most usefull when you require functionality outside the transaction domain, e.g. document indexing or network indexing.